# Cannot post on Japanese message board because I'm using Tor

Tags: network-configuration, troubleshooting, blocked-services

I can read and write some Japanese and I wanted to post on a Japanese message board that interests me.
But they only allow Japanese IPs. So I came up with the idea of using Tor Browser and setting my Exitnode to `{jp}`.

But now when I want to sent my post there I get the error message:

> ＥＲＲＯＲ：公開ＰＲＯＸＹからの投稿は受け付けていません！！(1)

I've tried switching identities several times, but I keep getting this message.
Apparently, they do not allow public proxies.
Is there any way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If this is Futaba (2chan) then you are out of luck. It keeps one of the largest public proxy lists in the world. You'll do better buying some really good private proxies or very small VPNs or VPSes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try multiple VPN services to see if one works, but it could end up being blocked at any point. If accessing these sites matters enough to you, setting up your own VPN on a VPS in Japan (ideally from a popular Japan-based company) might be worth the trouble and money.